# How to trigger two hovers when hovering over single element CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to hover both classes **col-md-3** and **overlay-text** via one hover.  When hover over image I want to trigger second hover, in this case over text.

> If CSS somehow could support if/else statements, I would wrote if
>   **col-md-3** is hovered then hover **overlay-text**.

```css
.overlay-text {
  background-color: #79b13c;
  color: white;
  z-index: 50;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 270px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out, font-size 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out, font-size 0.5s;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out, font-size 0.5s;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out, font-size 0.5s;
}

.overlay-text:hover {
  content: "";
  background-color: #328ba6;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s, font-size 0.5s;
  line-height: 2;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.overlay-text:hover::after {
  transition: ease-in-out 1s, font-size 1s;
}

.col-md-3 {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.col-md-3 img {
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.col-md-3 img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -10%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -10%, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay-text-blank {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row tiles">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img alt="text" src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" class="img-fluid">
      <div class="overlay-text">Custom text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**FiddleJS Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/57nvbfud/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options here:

First one change `hover` to `img:hover + .overlay-text`

Second one is change both `hover` in `col-md-3:hover`.

```css
.overlay-text {
 background-color: #79b13c;
 color: white;
 z-index: 50;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
 width: 270px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.4rem;
 font-weight: 600;
 -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out, font-size 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out, font-size 0.5s;
 -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out, font-size 0.5s;
 transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out, font-size 0.5s;
}

.col-md-3:hover .overlay-text{
 content:"";
 background-color: #328ba6;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: ease-in-out 0.5s, font-size 0.5s;
 line-height: 2;
 font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.col-md-3:hover .overlay-text::after{
 transition: ease-in-out 1s, font-size 1s;
}

.col-md-3 {
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 padding-left: 5px;
 padding-right: 5px;
}

.col-md-3 img {
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}

.col-md-3:hover img{
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-10%,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,-10%,0);
 cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay-text-blank {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.8rem;
 font-weight: 600;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row tiles">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img alt="text" src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" class="img-fluid">
      <div class="overlay-text">Custom text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exacly what I meant. Perfect solution!